# Does OpenCV 2.4.3 for iOS use Accelerate Framework under the hood?

Tags: ios, opencv, frameworks

I have recently downloaded opencv for a spin on an iOS project from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.3/opencv2.framework.zip/download.)

It seemed to require the Accelerate Framework in opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h which seems to deal
primarily with video capture. What I am curious to know if someone know if any significant CV algorithms are in fact taking advantage of the framework on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cap_ios.h, as you say, is only used for video and photo capture. This is the only part of openCV that requires the Accelerate framework, so it's use can't go much beyond that. But it is not even required: I am able to run CVVideoCamera video capture using cap_ios.h whether or not the framework is included.

The only reference  to it [in the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html) is

"The Accelerate framework provides some CPU-accelerated DSP filters..."

So... I *don't* think any significant algorithms are using it. `cap_ios.h` is a new feature in 2.4.3 , and the *only* objective-C interface in openCV, which might explain the hesitant use and mention of the framework.